# Flowers for Montessori primary classroom?

Tags: pre-schooler, education, teacher

This may be a bit outside the normal question scope here, but it's worth a shot.

Like at most Montessori schools, parents at our daughters' school have a variety of volunteer roles. In one of our girls' classrooms (it's a "primary" class, which in the Montessori system means 3, 4, and 5-year-olds) we are signed up to provide the flowers for the flower arrangement area this month.

There are about 16-18 kids in the class. We are bringing flowers each Monday this month, I gather. What kind(s) of flowers should we be bringing, and how many?

Comment: Have you asked the teacher?

Comment: Is your question about what flowers are best for arranging, or if any flowers have special meaning in Montessori-thinking?

Comment: More what flowers are best, and how many of them we'll need.

Answer (score 3):

Tough ones. Kids have a way of not being delicate with these things. Especially if you're trying to arrange them properly, they'll take a bruising.

Different colored and shaped ones. A set of all white flowers might be beautiful for a wedding, but children will not be impressed.

Ones with long stems. Otherwise they'll be hard to arrange. They'll probably need to be shortened for each child, but better to start with a long stem than without.

And probably cheap ones or ones picked from the side of the road or gardens, because you'll be going through a *lot* of them.

(For amounts, I do not know. My little one seems quite impressed if she puts 5 different flowers in a vase, but I do not know the expectations of your teacher. I would ask them for information)

Comment: I'd also avoid roses (thorns!) and _maybe_ lillies (big and interesting, but may fall apart easily).